# How to get the average packet rate per ip for a port?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, iptables, ddos

Is it possible with iptables to limit inbound packets by source-ip based on the number of average inbound packets for all source-ips? If so, how?

I'd like to limit new ips to the average inbound packets of all previous ips on average with a slight burst.

This is to not have to increase the packet limits when the number of requests grows, so it should be kind of a very simply anomaly detection.

Answer (score 2):

This is more the job of QOS in conjunction with iptables. Basically, you use the MARK target to bind it to QoS rules set up with tc (from the iproute package).